# How do visited websites know which website sent the visitor?

Tags: browser, tracking, google-analytics

In the below given two scenes, do browsers tell the visited website server as to which website was the user on before reaching this/current website? In other words, suppose I was on Website1 and I clicked a link which led me to website2. Would WSite2 know that I was on WSite1? And what if I directly type WSite2 address in the URL bar?

- Assuming that no google analytics or any codes etc have been setup?
- And assuming google tag manager/analytics have been setup.

Answer (score 3):

The main way a website can tell which website sent a visitor is through the [HTTP Referer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033876) header.  When you click on a link on a web page, your browser can use the Referer header to add that page's address to the HTTP request for the new page.

The Referer header is optional.  It can potentially be disabled in your browser's settings, or removed by privacy software, or obscured by using a proxy website.  It is not sent when you type an address directly in the browser URL bar, rather than following a link.  [whatismyreferer.com](https://www.whatismyreferer.com/) shows you the contents of the Referer header when you visit it, so you can experiment with what your browser is sending.

Google Analytics code can do [cross-domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033876), where visits to separate websites can be analysed as a single session.  There are also lots of other ways of using code on a website that could let WSite 2 know you have previously visited WSite 1.    However, they generally need some sort of co-operation between the website owners, and can't necessarily tell that you have gone directly from one site to the other without visiting anything else in between.  This blog explains [the Many Ways Websites Track You Online](https://www.howtogeek.com/115483/htg-explains-learn-how-websites-are-tracking-you-online/)